# Refresh ListFragment from another fragment AND fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a program with two Fragments in a ViewPager, one regular Fragment and one ListFragment. I have an AlertDialog pop up in the regular Fragment to add data into an SQLite database. However, I want to refresh the list in my ListFragment with the data from my regular Fragment. After struggling for days, I have given up and want to post my code here to see if anyone can help me fix this issue. Thank you in advance to any responses.

Here is my ListFragment class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ClassListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Double> currentGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<Double> desiredGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<Double> finalGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ClassListAdapter adapter;
    private DataHandler dh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dh = new DataHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        dh.open();
        adapter = new ClassListAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), classes, currentGrades, desiredGrades, finalGrades);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        refreshList();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        dh.deleteRow(ids.get(position));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void refreshList() {
        adapter.clear();
        ids.clear();
        Cursor data = dh.returnData();
        if (data.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ids.add(data.getLong(0));
                classes.add(data.getString(1));
                currentGrades.add(data.getDouble(2));
                desiredGrades.add(data.getDouble(3));
                finalGrades.add(data.getDouble(4));
            }while(data.moveToNext());
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my Fragment class, with custom methods unnecessary to the problem removed:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuickCalc extends Fragment {

    private TextView tv;
    private DataHandler dh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quickcalc_layout, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dh = new DataHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    }

public void clicked() {
        EditText currentGradeBox = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.currentGrade);
        EditText desiredGradeBox = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.desiredGrade);
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        int rbID = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        final Double currentGrade = Double.parseDouble(currentGradeBox.getText().toString());
        final String desiredGrade = desiredGradeBox.getText().toString();
        Object[] values = getValues(rbID, desiredGrade);
        if (values != null) {
            final String answer = doCalculations(values, currentGrade);
            if (Double.parseDouble(answer) <= 100.0) {
                if (String.valueOf(values[0]).contains("A")) {
                    tv.setText("You need to get a " + answer + "% in order to get an " + values[0] + " (" + values[1] + "%) in this class.\n \nWould you like to save this to your class list?");
                }
                else {
                    tv.setText("You need to get a " + answer + "% in order to get a " + values[0] + " (" + values[1] + "%) in this class.\n \nWould you like to save this to your class list?");
                }
                Button addButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.addClass);
                addButton.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        alert.setTitle("Add Class");
                        final EditText className = new EditText(getActivity());
                        className.setHint("Class Name");
                        alert.setView(className);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dh.open();
                                dh.insertData(className.getText().toString(), currentGrade, Double.parseDouble(desiredGrade), Double.parseDouble(answer));
                                dh.close();
                            }
                        });
                        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
                        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                tv.setText("The grade that you wish to achieve is impossible.");
            }
        }
        else {
            tv.setText("ERROR in one of the text boxes. Please fix it.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where do you call refreshList(), do you call only from onStart? In this case it won't work.. you need onRefresh

Comment: There is no onRefresh override method, the ListFragment class extends ListFragment. I tried calling it in onCreate, onCreateView, onStart, and onResume, and all of them called it on the creation of the Fragment, and then did not call it again until I closed and reopened the app. I want to be able to refresh the list when data is added from my other class (the Fragment class which extends Fragment).

Comment: yes, you need to create onRefersh(or the way you want to name it) and call it from other class, did you try it?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to change refreshList() to a static method if I wanted to do that? Or could I just instantiate a new ClassListFragment in the QuickCalc class?